# Copy row from a sheet to another if there isn't exist in Google Sheets by app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello I have two sheets in the same SpreadSheet in Google sheets and I want to compare every row of sheet1 with rows of sheet2 and if a row doesn't exist copy to sheet2 in the last row. I used a script to copy entire sheet1 to sheet2 but the first sheet is from an export so I want to update sheet2 only with the new rows. Because of sorting there isn't copying row to row so I need this code to check for new rows and copy them.
Below I have the code that I used to copy the first time the sheet1 to sheet2:

```
function copyExportColumns() {
  var result = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("If you sure click OK, if not close the window");
  if(result === SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
    var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet2");

    // get source range
    var source = copySheet.getRange(2,1,1000, 26)
    // get destination range
    var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(2,1,1000,26);

    // copy values to destination range
    source.copyTo(destination);

    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();        
    s.autoResizeColumns(1, 26);
    s.autoResizeRows(1, 1000);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

#### Add new rows

```
function addNewRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  const ua = [];
  let nvs = ssh.getRange(2, 1, ssh.getLastRow() - 1, ssh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().reduce((a,r,i) => {
    if(!~ub.indexOf(r.join(""))) {
      a.ua.push(r);
      a.ub.push(r.join(""));
    }
    return a;
  },{ua:[],ub:[],getUa:function(){return this.ua}}).getUa();
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, nvs.length, nvs[0].length).setValues(nvs);
}
```

Comment: I get an error and I can't find why! Could you help me more?
This is the error: "ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ua' before initialization"

Comment: Try it again.  I"m not sure where I was going  before

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time! I tried again the new function but copied again all the rows! I need only the "new" rows... Could you explain to me the comparison (if statement) to understand and maybe to resolve it? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Try it again.  I changed the way the comparison array is constructed

Comment: If you wish to learn more about this then please study the array.reduce method and all other comparison are explained in any javascript reference